# unsigned char ** to opencv mat

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, double-pointer

I'm almost there but I can't quite understand how to convert

```
unsigned char ** to a cv::Mat
```

I know that the .data part of a cv::Mat is uchar*

I'm using a function that returns and image in the form of...

```
unsigned char ** output;
```

But the rest of my code uses cv::Mat's. I don't have the source for the lib I'm using either so don't really know what it's doing.

**Edit**
Thanks for the help guys, I've done this...

```
cv::Mat TempMat = cv::Mat(h, w, CV_8UC1, *output);
imshow("this is a test",TempMat);
```

but the image is black so I now need to find out if there's actually anything there or not.

Sorry for lack of research i'm on a tight deadline, no it's not homework, trying to get something ready to show results to a Professor!

Comment: Do you know the width and height of the double pointer you are returning?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use [Mat constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a9fa74fb14362d87cb183453d2441948f) with a pointer to data:

```
 // constructor for matrix headers pointing to user-allocated data
    Mat(int _rows, int _cols, int _type, void* _data, size_t _step=AUTO_STEP);
    Mat(Size _size, int _type, void* _data, size_t _step=AUTO_STEP);
```

You have to convert `void**` to `void*` and after this use it.

Comment: Thanks, I've had a go at doing that. See edit for the next problem

Comment: @Oliver9523 what is the format of input data (`void**`)? If it's a pointer to two-dimensional array of image data than you should convert it to one-dimensional.

Comment: I'm assuming it's a 2d array, thanks. I'll have a look at converting it.

Comment: +1 for Astor comment: if your data is a 2D array, you must, say, preallocate your cv::Mat and copy the data row by row.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should remove `*` at

```
cv::Mat TempMat = cv::Mat(h, w, CV_8UC1, *output);
```

make it just like this:

```
cv::Mat TempMat = cv::Mat(h, w, CV_8UC1, output);
```